# Spark Scala: Efficient way to compare words in two strings

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm looking for an efficient method that is conducive to parallelism in spark that will compare words in two strings. The two string will be a column in two datasets.
The task is simple: count the number of matching words in one string that occur in another string. 
e.g., "AA BB CC" , "AA A CC DD" -> 2 (words AA and CC)
e.g., "BB CC" , "AA A CC DD" -> 1 (words CC)

Is there an efficient method in scala that I can apply instead of writing a loop to go through each word in one string?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on "will be a column in two datasets"? Do you need to do a `crossJoin()` to compare every possible value? What do the datasets look like?

Comment: DS1 will have a column containing the first string; DS2 will have a column containing the second string. These datasets may have additional columns. I will have to take each string from the first dataset and compare with every string in the second dataset and see how many common words there are in each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the string, convert to set, and find intersection

```
def common_words(x: String, y: String) = x.split(" ").toSet.intersect(y.split(" ").toSet)
```

Usage:

```
common_words("AA BB CC", "AA A CC DD")
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(AA, CC)
scala> common_words("BB CC", "AA A CC DD")
res4: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(CC)
```

Comment: Thank you and because I want the number of matches, I will just have to perform a count operation after that.